# SQL needed: sum over Quantity by Month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with values like this:

```
ItemId  Item    RegisterDate    Quantity
1       Item1   02-01-2023          35
1       Item1   03-01-2023          40
2       Item2   02-01-2023          40
2       Item2   02-03-2023          15
2       Item2   02-04-2023          30
6       Item6   02-04-2023          35
6       Item6   25-04-2023          20
```

How do I get the following results?

```
ItemId  Item    Jan Feb Mar Apr
1       Item1   75  0   0   0
2       Item2   40  0   15  30
6       Item6   0   0   0   55
```

Comment: unfortunately extracting month from date differ between implementations of SQL. So you'll need to say which SQL

Comment: Use CASE to build a conditional sum and MONTH to fetch the month from the entire date.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `MONTH()` function here:

```sql
SELECT
    ItemId,
    Item,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(RegisterDate) = 1  THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Jan,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(RegisterDate) = 2  THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Feb,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(RegisterDate) = 3  THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Mar,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(RegisterDate) = 4  THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Apr,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(RegisterDate) = 5  THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS May,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(RegisterDate) = 6  THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Jun,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(RegisterDate) = 7  THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Jul,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(RegisterDate) = 8  THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Aug,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(RegisterDate) = 9  THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Sep,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(RegisterDate) = 10 THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Oct,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(RegisterDate) = 11 THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Nov,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(RegisterDate) = 12 THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS Dec
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    ItemId,
    Item
ORDER BY
    ItemId;
```

If you need to also cater for the year being possibly different, then you should update your expected output.  The above query assumes you want a report for a single year.

Comment: Your query will do also for different years, see https://dbfiddle.uk/FQMo1gFf, unless it is intended to output the year.

Answer (score 1):

use the PIVOT operator

```
select *
from   (
           select ItemId, Item, 
                  mth = left(datename(month, RegisterDate), 3), 
                  Quantity
           from   your_table
       ) d
       pivot
       (
           sum(Quantity)
           for mth in ([Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr])
       ) p
```

Comment: Maybe you could extend this because this query will return NULL values, but OP requested zero instead.